# Match and sum columns from 2 dataframes having unequal rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 df with columns A,B and C,D
I want to compare values from A with C and add the values from B where ever there is a match.
E.g.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 23], ['b', 53], ['c', 23], ['d', 12], ['e', 34]], columns=['A', 'B'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['c', 1], ['e', 1], ['b', 1]], columns=['C', 'D'])
```

Here c,e and b are matching.

My result should be 23+34+53=110. I am planning to store this result in col E as df2['E'] = result

Basically a sumx function in DAX

Comment: What is the significance of column D? And you're going to store the same value in all rows of df2?

Comment: column D will have other information which I did not put in for this example.
Yes i intent to store the same value in all the rows of d2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need ?

```
df2['E']=df1.loc[df1.A.isin(df2.C),'B'].sum()
df2
Out[377]: 
   C  D    E
0  c  1  110
1  e  1  110
2  b  1  110
```

Comment: Yes thank you :). Which functions do I study for this? I tried `df1.B[df1.A==df2.C].sum()` but it was giving me error.

Comment: @NeilS fucntion of `isin`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `DataFrame.merge()` method

```py
df_merged = df1.merge(df2, left_on='A', right_on='C')
result = df_merged['B'].sum()  # 110
df2['E'] = result
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is using `map` of series

```
df2['E'] = df2['C'].map(df1.set_index('A')['B']).sum()

In [64]: df2
Out[64]:
   C  D    E
0  c  1  110
1  e  1  110
2  b  1  110
```